# Knockout - validation group not binding

Tags: javascript, html, validation, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I have a validation group that catches errors for a customer object that contains a contact object. There are 4 required fields in the contact object. Sometime when I fill in these required fields for the Contact the errors are retained in the customerErrors validation group. I have stepped through and checked each property of the contact to make sure that the values are present and I have checked their isValid() property and they are all true. I am declaring the extensions on these variable in the view like so:

```
<div class="right-column" style="width:45%;" data-bind="with: ContactsDTO()[0]">
    <h6>Contact</h6>
    <label class="required">First Name<input type="text" class="k-textbox big-textbox" data-bind="value: FirstName.extend({ required: { message: 'First Name is a required field.', params: true } })"></label>
    <label class="required">Last Name<input type="text" class="k-textbox big-textbox" data-bind="value: LastName.extend({ required: { message: 'Last Name is a required field.', params: true } })"></label>
    <label class="required">Email<input type="text" class="k-textbox big-textbox" data-bind="value: Email.extend({ required: { message: 'Email is a required field.', params: true } })"></label>
    <label class="required">Business Phone<input type="text" class="k-textbox big-textbox" data-bind="value: BusinessPhone.extend({ required: { message: 'Phone is a required field.', params: true } })"></label>
</div>
```

I am initializing the validation on the viewModel like so:

```
self.estimateErrors = ko.validation.group(self.estimate());
self.customerErrors = ko.validation.group(self.estimate().CustomerDTO(), { deep: true });
self.workOrderErrors = ko.validation.group(self.estimate().WorkOrdersDTO(), { deep: true });
self.estimateSalesRepErrors = ko.validation.group(self.estimate().EstimateSalesRepsDTO(), { deep: true });
self.estimateScopeServiceErrors = ko.validation.group(self.estimate().EstimateScopeServicesDTO(), { deep: true });
ko.validation.init({ insertMessages: false, errorsAsTitle: false, decorateElement: true, errorElementClass: 'error', parseInputAttributes: true });
```

I haven't been able to find anyone with a similar problem, so any help would be great.

Comment: Have you tried extending the properties on your viewmodel instead of in the view?

Comment: Yes, I did try that and I get the same behavior. The reason I am doing it in the view is so that I only have to do it in one place since it is a Create/Edit page.

Comment: Have you tried initializing the validation framework `ko.validation.int` before calling `ko.validation.group` ?

Comment: @DaveB I just tried your suggestion and I am still getting the same behavior as before.